# Utility Application whose view is not in the window hierarchy?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I try to present an other `ViewController` from `MainViewController`.
This is the code which worked every time for me ?

```
FirststartViewController *FVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"firstStarter"];
[self presentViewController:FVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And every time I get this error: `Warning: Attempt to present <FirststartViewController: 0xaa27030> on <MainViewController: 0xaa2f730> whose view is not in the window hierarchy`!

I tried moving from `-viewDidLoad` to `-viewWillAppear` as mentioned in other posts with this error but error still exists and nothing happens.

Comment: How about doing it in `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: Where this code is being executed from?

Comment: thanks view die appear works :))